# WSDL Request response format different in Soap UI and WSDL2Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

I have a wsdl file, I have generated java files by using "java org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java -o . -d Session -s -p  org.att HandlingRequest2.wsdl" command in linux system then create a server and a client, which are working fine then I take a TCPDUMP and get the request and response format, But when I process this wsdl file using the SOAPUI it generated different request format which are not working in my server getting Error Code 500 from Server, pls suggest.

Request format by TCPDUMP:-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <requestReceiver xmlns="http://connect.ags.com"><req><extra1 xsi:nil="true"/>
        <extra2 xsi:nil="true"/>
        <extra3 xsi:nil="true"/>
        <mdn>8802649138</mdn>
        <req_type>102</req_type>
        <tid xsi:nil="true"/>
        <time xsi:nil="true"/>
        </req>
        </requestReceiver>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Request format by SOAPUI:-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:con="http://connect.ags.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <con:requestReceiver>
         <con:req>
            <con:extra1>?</con:extra1>
            <con:extra2>?</con:extra2>
            <con:extra3>?</con:extra3>
            <con:mdn>?</con:mdn>
            <con:req_type>?</con:req_type>
            <con:tid>?</con:tid>
            <con:time>?</con:time>
         </con:req>
      </con:requestReceiver>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: what is error in server logs ?

Comment: when I am firing the Soap UI request format I am getting http error 500 (Internal server error). I am confused that firstly why the defernt request format showing th soap UI and this request xml not acception by server.

Comment: the 500 response is in the XML? In the XML from tcpdump you had the last `</soapenv:Envelope>` tag missing, was that intentional?